# Can variant familiar imps and quasits reform their bodies?

Tags: dnd-5e, familiars

The variant familiar forms of the imp and the quasit as described in the Monster Manual are not the same as familiars summoned by the spell Find Familiar, or of the sort summoned by a Pact of the Chain Warlock. They are intended to be actual demons or devils (not a spirit), and a DM-controlled NPC.

Given these qualifications, if one is killed, it is not re-summoned with the Find Familiar spell. However, it is still a demon or devil. As per the Monster Manual, such creatures slain on the Prime Material re-form in the Abyss or the Nine Hells respectively. Could such a familiar, if killed by say, a fireball, be re-summoned with a gate, or other portal type spell?

*I apologize, I don't have any of my books with me and cannot reference page numbers for any of this. Feel free to correct the question to comply with actual rules. I have an NPC who depends upon this trait of quasits, and while I am perfectly willing to hand-wave any RAW restrictions, I'd prefer to keep it within the letter, if not the spirit of the rules.*

Answer (score 5):

IMP are a devils, and Quasits are demons. So, we will look at both.

Both can return to the prime material through different means. Devils and demons can both be summoned with their true name, and both demons and devils can be summoned with *gate* spell.

> DEVIL TRUE NAMES AND TALISMANS
>
> ... every devil above a lemure in station also has a true name that it keeps secret. ... A mortal who learns a devil's true name can use powerful summoning magic to call the devil from the Nine Hells and bind it into service.
>
> ... [I]mps are truly content to be summoned, and they easily commit to serving a summoner as a familiar, but they still do their utmost to corrupt those who summon them.

DEMON TRUE NAMES

> ... every demon lord and every demon of type 1 through 6 has a true name that
>   it keeps secret. ... A mortal who learns a demon's true name can use
>   powerful summoning magic to call the demon from the Abyss and exercise some measure of control over it. However, most demons brought to the Material Plane in this, manner do everything in their power to wreak havoc or sow discord and strife.

Moreover, demons (like quasit) want to escape the abyss:

> Abyssal Invasions. Wherever they wander across the Abyss, demons search for portals to the other planes.  They crave the chance to slip free of their native realm and spread their dark influence across the multiverse ...

The quotes are all from the Monster Manual, from the Devil and Demon sections respectively.

The ability to summon demons and devils isn't covered in the PHB, beyond *gate*, but there are spells in one of the WoTC Unearthed Arcana articles: [Old Black Magic.](https://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/07_UA_That_Old_Black_Magic.pdf)  It offers a variant Tiefling race that has demon and devil summoning abilities.

Comment: Thank you. I obviously wrote my question in a hurry and sloppily swapped imps for quasits. I have re-formed the question to apply to both. Thanks for answering both the question as asked and the question as intended. :)

Comment: That strikes me as a lot of block-quoted text relative to the commentary/explanation... any chance some of the quotes could be trimmed back a bit? (I know we're not going to get in copyright *trouble*, but I like erring on the side of including the minimal quote needed to make a point.)

Comment: I further edited this answer to trim the block quotes, and to add a link to the UA article you cited.  Feel free to roll back or edit again if you feel it doesn't fit your answer.